# Display all records from list of array in php

Tags: php

I have a script which runs pretty well, it displays 2 records at a time. I want to actually display all the records from the array data. I am not very familiar with jquery and the script uses jquery.

Basically it works like this... the user submits a question on one page and then the question submitted displays on the a second page. You can try it here:

Submit questions: http://www.webcastviewer.com/post/submit.php

Lists questions: http://www.webcastviewer.com/post/list.php

On the "List" page: Currently it lists the two most recent questions. The most recent question is in blue/larger font at the top. The change I want is that I want it to list ALL questions with the most recent at the top (as it is now). Currently older questions disappear after two entries. I want it to show all submissions.

App.js (jquery code )
http://www.webcastviewer.com/post/js/app.js

Page code for displaying 2 records.

```
    <?php
//read questions
$question_file_path = 'server/question.list';
if(!file_exists($question_file_path)){    
    $questions = array();
}
else {
    $questions = json_decode(file_get_contents($question_file_path), true);
}

?>
<body>
    <div class="p-3" id="page_list">
        <?php
        if(count($questions) > 0){
            ?>
            <div class="questions-list">
            <?php
        }
        else{
            ?>
            <div class="questions-list questions--empty">
            <?php
        }
        ?>
            <div class="alert alert-primary questions-alert">
                <h1 id="question_new"><?php echo isset($questions[0]) ? $questions[0]: '&nbsp;'  ?></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-info questions-alert">
                <h4 id="question_old"><?php echo isset($questions[1]) ? $questions[1] : '&nbsp;' ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger questions-alert-empty">
                <h1 id="question_new text-danger">There isn't question.</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You haven't shown an actual attempt though. Please note: Stackoverflow is NOT a code writing service. If you want to give it a try, and come back to us when you encounter an issue, we can assist then.

Comment: You need to use the for loop for displaying the data from array

Answer (score 1):

Please look at how you can do it.

I have improved some part of code and commented on them as well.

**Note:** Try to improve your mixing of PHP with HTML and avoid using it.

```
<div class="p-3" id="page_list">
    //Added ternary operator instead of typical if else.
    <div class="<?= count($questions) > 0 ? 'questions-list' : 'questions--empty'  ?>">
    <?php 
    //checking if has records else show message
        if(count($questions) > 0){
    ?>
        <?php foreach($questions as $question) ?>
            <div class="alert alert-primary questions-alert">
                <h1 id="question_new"><?php echo isset($question) ? $question: '&nbsp;'  ?></h1>
            </div>
        <?php }

    }else{ ?>

        <div class="alert alert-danger questions-alert-empty">
            <h1 id="question_new text-danger">There isn't question.</h1>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```